# Is it bad to use else if instead of else in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering when writing if statements can you just use an else if and leave an else statement out of the code or use an "else if" instead of an else by adding some condition that will evaluate true.

I'm quite new to javascript so just trying to understand if it's possible but just considered bad practise.

thanks

Comment: They do different things and have different use cases. It's perfectly fine.

Comment: The question is why would you? You'd generally use `else if` it there are more than three options, but it can be used to match two specific conditions as well, if that's what you need.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: *"or use an "else if" instead of an else by adding some condition that will evaluate true."* - If you mean a condition that will *always* evaluate true then no, don't do that, just use an `else`. (Your suggestion would work, but what would be the point?)

Comment: I usually prefer not to have multi strophe if statements. But the language has them for when you feel you need them.

Comment: Thanks, I understood how it worked just wondered if it was possible to use it the other way or whether there was a technical reason not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> use an "else if" instead of an else by adding some condition that will evaluate true

This is a bad practice and should be avoided.

The `if...else if...` statement is an advanced form of `if…else` that allows JavaScript to make a correct decision out of several conditions.

The syntax of an `if-else-if` statement is used as follows −

```
if (expression 1){
   Statement(s) to be executed if expression 1 is true
}

else if (expression 2){
   Statement(s) to be executed if expression 2 is true
}

else if (expression 3){
   Statement(s) to be executed if expression 3 is true
}

else{
   Statement(s) to be executed if no expression is true
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I understood how it worked just wondered if it was possible to use it the other way or whether there was a technical reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "else if" without using "else" but you shouldn't use "else if" instead of "else"(instead of an else by adding some condition that will evaluate true), use "else if" when you have some additional condition besides condition defined in "if" and use "else" when you need to cover cases when all other conditions aren't true.

Answer (score 0):

I think using nested else...if statement is just fine, but you should use it when required and i think it will work fine in all programming languages if syntax is correct

Answer (score 0):

> or use an "else if" instead of an else

there is no such thing as an `else if` in JS, that are two separate statements.
This is a regular else-block containing only an if-statement, and therefore skipping the curly brackets.

```
if(condition) {
    //...
} else if(condition2){
    //...
} else if(condition3){
    //...
} else if(condition4){
    //...
} else {
    //...
}
```

is nothing else than this

```
if(condition) {
    //...
} else {
    if(condition2){
        //...
    } else {
        if(condition3){
            //...
        } else {
            if(condition4){
                //...
            } else {
                //...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> by adding some condition that will evaluate true.

Why would you want to do that? Why not just writing the code inside the else-block without the useless condition around it? (as long as it is useless)